# Centering content on page not starting from top left

Tags: javascript, html, css

In developing this web page I need a way to center the content (in this case "fdsa") into the center of the bottom part of the page.

Non centered image.

[image]

What I would like it to do.
[image]

All of the solutions and attempts I have come across consider that the content wants to be centered at the middle of the page not the middle of an area of a page. I thought I could make a bounding box around the area and center inside the bounding box but I'm not much a web developer and have no idea how to do it.

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <Title>FMA</Title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="center">    
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Future Market Analysis</h1>
                <h4>Change the way you trade today!</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <ul>
            <div class="center">
                <li>
                    <a onclick="showHome();">Home</a>
                    <a onclick="showRegister();">Register</a>
                    <a onclick="showLogin();">Login</a>
                    <a onclick="showStatus();">Status</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>

        <br />
        <br />

        <div id="home" class="home">
            fdsa
        </div>

        <div id="register" style="display: none;">
            <div id="wrapper">
                fdsa
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="login" style="display: none;">

        </div>

        <div id="status" style="display: none;">

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: QuickSand;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height:100%;
}

title{
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

home{

}



ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D1F2FF;
}

li {
    float: center;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #4CC5F5;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How does your html/css look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start using `flexbox`.

I also corrected the fact that you had a `div` element between the `ul` and `li`, which shouldn't be.

Another suggestion would be to add a `margin-top` to the `home` class instead of using those `<br>` tags.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: QuickSand;
  background-color: aliceblue;  
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
}
.home {
  flex: 1;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

title{
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D1F2FF;
}

li {
    float: center;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #4CC5F5;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">    
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Future Market Analysis</h1>
      <h4>Change the way you trade today!</h4>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a onclick="showHome();">Home</a>
        <a onclick="showRegister();">Register</a>
        <a onclick="showLogin();">Login</a>
        <a onclick="showStatus();">Status</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="home" class="home">
    fdsa
  </div>

  <div id="register" style="display: none;">
    <div id="wrapper">
      fdsa
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="login" style="display: none;">

  </div>

  <div id="status" style="display: none;">

  </div>

</div>
```

When old browser support is needed, `display: table` will work as the best alternative with similar requirements.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: QuickSand;
  background-color: aliceblue;  
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.home {
  display: table-cell;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

title{
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D1F2FF;
}

li {
    float: center;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #4CC5F5;
}
.center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="center">    
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Future Market Analysis</h1>
        <h4>Change the way you trade today!</h4>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <a onclick="showHome();">Home</a>
          <a onclick="showRegister();">Register</a>
          <a onclick="showLogin();">Login</a>
          <a onclick="showStatus();">Status</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />

  <div class="row">
    <div id="home" class="home">
      fdsa
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="register" style="display: none;">
      fdsa
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <div class="row">
    <div id="login" style="display: none;">

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div id="status" style="display: none;">

    </div>
  </div>

  
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Would you mind a simple sentence or two explaining what "flex" is?

Comment: `flex` is more than a simple sentence or two :), read here http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html and here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

A simple example.
https://jsfiddle.net/85y6ts4c/

```css
  

  #content{
  height: 300px;
  display: table;
  width:500px;
  text-align: center;
}
#content p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<p>
This is center 
</p>
</div>
```